# Where is "request" object instantiated when using a JSP file?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

When I create a WelcomeServlet.java file, I extend HttpServlet and can implement:
doGet and doPost methods.
Both of those methods are inserted by default with parameters named req and resp:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }
```

However, here in my JSP file I can freely use "request" which I have to assume is of HttpServletRequest given the ways I've been using it. (I can also attach cookies and variables to it if I Want)

```
    <%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


    <% 

    File jsp = new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));

%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%= jsp.toString() %>

</body>
</html>
```

My questions are:

1. Where is this request object being stored? I don't see anywhere it could be stored.
   EDIT: I just learned "the request object is created and initialized by the application server from the HTTP request received from the browser."
2. Where does it say that "request" is the default name of the variable?
   (If I insert doGet and doPost, it's name is "req")

NOTE: I am using Eclipse and got to this point by creating a Dynamic Web Project

Comment: JSP file is "compiled" to Java file, and the class in this Java file extends `HttpServlet` class. More details e.g at https://www.guru99.com/jsp-life-cycle.html

Comment: Fantastic link thanks Wow. That answers it perfectly. Do you want to provide Answer or shall I?   @JozefChocholacek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP file is "compiled" to Java file, and the class in this Java file extends `HttpServlet` class. More details e.g at https://www.guru99.com/jsp-life-cycle.html